# Table won't sort cells without formulas

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I have the table below:

[image: 1]

My formulas from D2 to G999 is:

=IFERROR(IF(OR(INDEX('Client List'!$1:$1048576, MATCH(A2,'Client List'!$A:$A, 0), MATCH($D$1,'Client List'!$1:$1, 0))="Complete - Late",INDEX('Client List'!$1:$1048576, MATCH(A2,'Client List'!$A:$A, 0), MATCH($D$1,'Client List'!$1:$1, 0))="Complete - On Time"),NOW(),IF(OR(INDEX('Client List'!$1:$1048576, MATCH(A2,'Client List'!$A:$A, 0), MATCH($D$1,'Client List'!$1:$1, 0))="In Progress",INDEX('Client List'!$1:$1048576, MATCH(A2,'Client List'!$A:$A, 0), MATCH($D$1,'Client List'!$1:$1, 0))="To Do"),"Pending","NA")),"-")

I have a VBA that converts anything that is returned as a date into text. You can see them highlighted in yellow.

When I go into the Client List sheet, and sort by Advisor column, the cells that have been converted into text don't move.

Can someone help me or explain why?

Column A is also a mirror of column A in the Client List sheet using formula:

=IF('Client List'!A2="","",'Client List'!A2)

I tried to use the sheet with column A hard coded but it still was not sorting correctly

Comment: If columns A and C are both hard-coded (pasted by value) and your sort range encompasses those two columns, then it looks like your sort should work.  All the other columns appear dependent on those two.

Comment: Is your VBA only adjusting the format of those date->text? Or is it removing the formula? Because then that would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the same formula that you copy down multiple rows, sorting that formula behaves in a similar way-- it's effectively the same relative formula whether sorted or copied.

Your underlying goal becomes sorting the hard data, and ignoring whether the formulas are also sorted out of convenience, knowing that they'll behave the same way in the same cells whether sorted or not.

In your case, it appears that columns A and C either need to hold a hard copy of the original data, or if they must contain a reference, then the remote data that they reference must be sorted instead.